# docker build question no permission to read from

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to build a docker image

I get this error

```
sudo docker build . -t django-demo
error checking context: 'no permission to read from '/home/benny/.ICEauthority''
```

any ideas why this is happening?

```
--------------------------
ubuntu 18.04
Docker version 18.09.9
```

Comment: have you tried ......sudo chmod -R 777 /home/benny/.ICEauthority  ?

Comment: yep ! benny@benny-ubuntu:~$ sudo chmod -R 777 /home/benny/.ICEauthority 
benny@benny-ubuntu:~$ sudo docker build . -t django-demo
error checking context: 'no permission to read from '/home/benny/.ICEauthority''

Comment: Are you trying to run this from your home directory?  It will try to tar up your entire home directory, including all of your dot files, and send it over an HTTP request to the Docker daemon.  Better to run this somewhere else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a new directory, place your Dockerfile in this new directory and then run your `sudo docker build . -t django-demo` command from that directory. This should solve your problem. Found related problems and solution in this [external thread](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6521).

Answer (score 10):

Generally to solve this kind of problem you should add a `.dockerignore` file in which you list all the files you don't want to be sent to the build's context (ie. the files that docker don't need to build your image).

In your case simply creating a `.dockerignore` with the following content should solve the issue :

```
.ICEauthority
```

Note that specifically in your case though, you should not run your `docker build` command directly from your home directory, because all the content of your home is being sent to the build's context (which is heavy, might make you run out of disk space or generate permission issues).